# Automatically select the options of multiple selection drop down for the edit page in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am beginner in ASP.NET Core. I need help with automatically selecting the options of a multi-selection dropdown.

I have a `class` model and a class can have multiple students. When I am creating the class, I have a dropdown that shows the student list and I can add the students to the class by selecting the options form the drop down.

But I am having issues automatically selecting those values for the edit page. The dropdown should keep those students selected from the list when the edit page loads so that the user can see which students are currently enrolled in the class. I am only seeing the students that are enrolled in the class as option of the dropdown. It should show all the students in the list but select the ones that belongs to the class.

My `class` model:

```
public class ClassModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Class ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClassID { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    //[Display(Name = "User ID")]
    //public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public int Occurence { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    //[GreaterThanOrEqualTo("From")]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Fees { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Instructor Assigned")]
    [ForeignKey("InstructorID")]
    public virtual int InstructorID { get; set; }
    public Instructor? Instructor { get; set; }

    // [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Student Assigned")]
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<int> StudentID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollment  { get; set; }
}
```

`EditClass.cshtml.cs` code:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly TestProject.Data.TestProjectContext _context;

    public EditModel(TestProject.Data.TestProjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Model.ClassModel Class_Info { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public ClassModelStudent Class_Student { get; set; }
    public Model.Instructor instructor { get; set; }
    public SelectList Instructors { get; set; }
    public SelectList Students { get; set; }    
    public MultiSelectList Class_Student { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectedStudents { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Class_Info = await _context.Class.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ClassID == id);
        var instructors = from i in _context.Instructor
                          orderby i.FirstName
                          select i;

        Instructors = new SelectList(instructors, "InstructorID", "FirstName");
var selectedstudents = from cs in _context.ClassModelStudent
                               join s in _context.User_Profile on cs.StudentsStudentID equals s.StudentID
                               select  new { cs.StudentsStudentID, s.FullName, s.PhoneNumber };
       
        SelectedStudents = new SelectList(selectedstudents, "StudentsStudentID", "FullName");

        Class_Student = SelectedStudents; 
        var students = from cs in _context.ClassModelStudent
                       join s in _context.User_Profile on cs.StudentsStudentID equals s.StudentID
                       select new { cs.StudentsStudentID, s.FullName, s.PhoneNumber };

        Students = new SelectList(students, "StudentsStudentID", "FullName", "PhoneNumber");
        // Class_Student.StudentsStudentID = id;
        
        //from s in _context.ClassModelStudent
        //                  orderby s.StudentsStudentID
        //                  select s;
        if (Class_Info == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(Class_Info).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Attach(Class_Student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!Class_InfoExists(Class_Info.ClassID))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool Class_InfoExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Class.Any(e => e.ClassID == id);
    }
}
```

`EditClass.cshtml` view markup:

```
@page
@model TestProject.Pages.Classes.EditModel

@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Class_Info</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Class_Info.ClassID" />
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.Occurence" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.Occurence" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.Occurence" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.Startdate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.Startdate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.Startdate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.From" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.From" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.From" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.To" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class_Info.To" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.To" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               @* <label asp-for="instructor.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="instructor.FirstName" class="form-control" />*@
                <label asp-for="Class_Info.InstructorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Class_Info.InstructorID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Instructors">
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Class_Info.InstructorID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               @* <label asp-for="instructor.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="instructor.FirstName" class="form-control" />*@
```

-- Select --

```
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Please advise. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to populate `Class_Student.StudentsStudentID` with the IDs of the selected students.

Comment: Hi @Mike , I have the StudentID’s from the database  attached to the class but how can I show them on the view side? How can I only select those students automatically on the dropdown list?

Comment: If `Class_Student.StudentsStudentID` contains the IDs of the selected students, they will automatically be selected in the dropdown: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#enabling-multiple-selections

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have modified the code above (in question) to populate Class_students. I can see all the students in the list but none of them gets selected. Please see the modified code above. Please advise what am I doing wrong here.